# Where is my software center?

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software center has disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109899/software-center-has-disappeared)

I'm an Ubuntu newbie. Have already used software cenetr to install a few stuff, but this week I went looking for it and can't find the program anywhere :-/
I'm sure I must be doing something wrong but can't figure out what it is. Can't find a program listing in Ubuntu. Software Center is not in the applications menu and I have no idea where else to look.
Anyone can help please...?

Answer (score 2):

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd> key (or called as <kbd>Super</kbd> key in linux) in keyboard to bring up dash, and search for `software center`. Click on it to launch.
- Alternatively press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type in `software-center` and press enter.
- If `software center` is removed somehow, enter following in terminal to install it.

  > sudo apt-get install software-center

Once launched, go to dash (the panel on left side), right click on icon of `software center` and select `Lock to launcher`.

Comment: I am using linux on a mac... wich keys do I press? thank you